# ES6 how to export object without its functions

Tags: model, ecmascript-6, export

How do I export an object without its functions?

A user model:

```
export default {
  data: {},

  sanitize (options) {
  },

  async insert (options) {
  },

  async find (options) {
  },

  async remove (options) {
  }
}
```

usage:

```
const result = await user.insert({ id: '123', name: 'haha xxxx', password: 'gskgsgjs' })
console.log(user)
```

result:

```
{ data: { id: '123', name: 'haha', _id: 59a40e73f63b17036e5ce5c4 },
  sanitize: [Function: sanitize],
  insert: [Function: insert],
  find: [Function: find],
  remove: [Function: remove] }
```

What I am after:

```
{ data: { id: '123', name: 'haha', _id: 59a40e73f63b17036e5ce5c4 }
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Using ES6 class:

```
export default class User {
  constructor(options) {
    this.data = this.sanitize(options)
  }

  sanitize (options) {
  }

  async insert (options) {
  }

  async find (options) {
  }

  async remove (options) {
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  let User =  new user()
  // Inject a doc.
  const result = await User.insert({ id: '123', name: 'haha xxxx', password: 'gskgsgjs' })
  console.log(User)
```

Result:

```
User {
  data: { id: '123', name: 'haha xxxx', _id: 59a4143e63f3450e2e0c4fe4 } }
```

Still, not exactly what I am after:

```
{ data: { id: '123', name: 'haha', _id: 59a40e73f63b17036e5ce5c4 }
```

Comment: What is `insert`? Why exactly you need to export it when you already have it as `user` property?

Comment: @estus sorry the result is actually correct. i misunderstood.

Comment: How is the user supposed to call `user.insert` if that method is not available on the object?

Comment: @FelixKling it is just a dummy code. it has that method in my actual code. my question is not about the probs in method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 classes rather than using an object. You can find an example [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/).

```
// A base class is defined using the new reserved 'class' keyword
class Polygon {
  // ..and an (optional) custom class constructor. If one is
  // not supplied, a default constructor is used instead:
  // constructor() { }
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  // Simple class instance methods using short-hand method
  // declaration
  sayName() {
    ChromeSamples.log('Hi, I am a ', this.name + '.');
  }

  sayHistory() {
    ChromeSamples.log('"Polygon" is derived from the Greek polus (many) ' +
      'and gonia (angle).');
  }

  // Method to get json string
  toJson() {
    return JSON.stringify({ name: this.name, height: this.height, weight: this.weight });
  }

  // We will look at static and subclassed methods shortly
}
```

Comment: You can add a `toJson()` function to the class and return a stringified JSON object or you can just return a new object as you desired to have print it like `console.log(result.toJson());`. I'm editing my answer.